# Why is the format in printf_s (Annex K) marked as restrict?

Tags: c, c11, restrict-qualifier

I am fully aware of the existence of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841881/why-is-the-format-in-printf-marked-as-restrict).

However, `printf_s` considers presence of specifier `%n` as an error, thus no write operation to format would ever be expected from `printf_s`. What sense does `restrict` make here?

Comment: The accepted answer on that post has *"Since restrict may or may not make code run faster, but it can never make it slower (assuming the compiler is sane), it should be used always"*

Comment: That answer also pointed out the exception "(unless) it makes no significant performance improvement in this specific case", as in this case, I cannot see any possibility even for insignificant performance improvement.

Comment: Those bullets are for weighing risk against benefit. Both must should to *not* use it, i.e. if there is substantial risk of UB and no real benefit, don't use it. But what you detailed is the lack of possibility for undefined behavior. Which means we are left with a potential improvement that carries no risk. So following the original advice, use it.

Comment: That was convincing, however other standard library functions like `strlen` did not think the same. I still wonder why would `printf_s` be any different.

Comment: You have to bear in mind that different people at different time periods work on the standardization of specific features. Sometimes they miss things that could be improved.

Comment: `strlen_s` was also from Annex K, entering the standard accompanied by `printf_s`. "Different time periods" does not explain this.

Comment: But people missing things *does* explain it. Wait on an answer if you wish, but I'll be pleasantly surprised if it goes deeper than this.

Comment: It's probably been simply copied from the similar `printf()` signature without change (that would explain why `strlen_s()` has no `restrict).

Answer (score 0):

A function parameter of pointer to character type can not only alias other function parameters but also global objects. In particular, since `printf` and `printf_s` modify `stdout`, any pointer to character type could, in principle, point to the same `FILE` object or other objects that an implementation might use for IO under the hood.

This is a bit far fetched, but basically this `restrict` here and in many other places says, don't try to be funny and use a separate character array for your format.

Comment: Do you mean stdout could be redirected to format? How could that be done?

Comment: Not redirected, used. `printf((char*)stdout)`, would otherwise be a valid call, provided that you know that the bytes in the `FILE` structure contain a null character and no `%` characters.

Comment: Then how about `wprintf_s`? Aliasing `FILE` as `wchar_t` causes UB regardless of `restrict` for breaking strict aliasing rule. That makes `wprintf_s((wchar_t*)stdout)` unnecessary to compromise to.